# How to handle multi input in react native generically?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to know why this code doesn't work :

```
<TextInput 
  style={style.inputLogin} 
  onChangeText={this.handleInputChange} 
  value={this.state.login} 
/>
```

with the function :

```
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
    console.log("name => ", [name]);
    console.log("value => ", value);
  }
```

I tried many things but i can't get the targeted form.
Should I make one function for each input ? seems to be stupid :/
event only contains the value of the form.
Sure I could do this :

```
 <TextInput 
  style={style.inputLogin} 
  onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({value})) 
  value={this.state.login} 
/>
```

But this is not what I am looking for. I would like something more generic that works for every input

Please help me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext)

> `onChangeText` Callback that is called when the text input's text
>   changes. Changed text is passed as a single string argument to the
>   callback handler.

So the value passed by onChangeText is a string, not an event.
In your handleInputChange you can treat `text` like

```
  handleInputChange = (text) => {
    console.log(text);
    // ...
  }
```

In order to handle multiple textInput with just a function, customize it like:

```
<TextInput 
  style={style.inputLogin} 
  onChangeText={(text) => this.handleInputChange(text, "Something to tell your function you're calling it from first textinput")} 
  value={this.state.login} 
/>
```

And then

```
  handleInputChange = (text, fromWhichTextInputAreYouCallingMe) => {
    console.log(text);
    this.setState({
      login: text
    });
  }
```